# How to convert yyyy mm dd to laravel date and insert into mysql date() column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, datetime

I am getting date from user on Laravel application from three different selects i.e. dd(1-31) mm(1-12) yyyy(1905-2016)

How do I convert it to php date and insert it into mysql column created by Laravel migrations using fol code:

```
$table->date('dateOfBirth')->nullable();
```

also, i want to validate the date using Laravel validator after composing it.

Comment: are you using jquery or javascript? try to fill a hidden field with these three values together and send it as an unique date. Doing that you can use a custom form request to validate the field by its name, check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's separate inputs (`Input::get('month')`, `Input::get('day')`, `Input::get('year')`), then you can just put it together as a string:

```
$date = Input::get('year')."-".Input::get('month')."-".Input::get('day');
```

You can also use Carbon to create it:

```
$date = Carbon::createFromDate(Input::get('year'),Input::get('month'), Input::get('day'));
```

Carbon will help you validate that the format is correct.

Comment: that seems to work but still, laravel validation cannot be done on carbon date created form inputs like: `'date' => 'required|date'`

Comment: You can pass it through with `$date->toDateString()`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you are posting you data to this controller:

```
class MyController
{
    ....
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //validate
        $this->validate($request, [
            'day' => 'required|integer|min:1|max:31',
            'month' => 'required|integer|min:1|max:12',
            'year' => 'required|integer|min:1905|max:'.date('Y'),
        ]);

        //parse
        $day = $request->input('day');
        $month = $request->input('month');
        $year = $request->input('year');

        $dateOfBirth = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($year,$month,$day);

        //persist
        if($dateOfBirth) {
            $model = new Model();
            $model->dateOfBirth = $dateOfBirth->toDateString();
            ...
            $model->save();
        } else {
            echo "Problem parsing date";
        }
    }
}
```

My opinio here is that you should use a calendar component to avoid problems like `February "30"`.

Comment: feb 30 validation is the real problem....

Comment: guess will have to use javascript to compose the date on client side... What is colander component?